# When upgrading a package with pip it goes on an infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Where is there good pip documentation? I feel like I must be stupid because pip always ends up getting screwd in every single machine/OS I use.

Whenever I try to upgrade any package pip just iterates all versions without doing anything

Why is this happening?
Example

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

Terminal:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (62.1.0)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-62.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/58/9efbfe68482dab9557c49d433a60fff9efd7ed8835f829eba8297c2c124a/setuptools-62.1.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=26ead7d1f93efc0f8c804d9fafafbe4a44b179580a7105754b245155f9af05a8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/) (requires-python:>=3.7). Requested setuptools from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/58/9efbfe68482dab9557c49d433a60fff9efd7ed8835f829eba8297c2c124a/setuptools-62.1.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=26ead7d1f93efc0f8c804d9fafafbe4a44b179580a7105754b245155f9af05a8 has inconsistent version: filename has '62.1.0', but metadata has '62.1.0'
  Using cached setuptools-62.1.0.tar.gz (2.5 MB)
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
```

And this will iterated for god knows how long if I don't cancel it, going over every version of any package specified
Here is the logs

```
2022-05-01T02:23:14,484 Using pip 21.0 from /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
2022-05-01T02:23:14,485 Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
2022-05-01T02:23:14,516 Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-81kutz95
2022-05-01T02:23:14,516 Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-y2gd2yu7
2022-05-01T02:23:14,516 Initialized build tracking at /tmp/pip-req-tracker-y2gd2yu7
2022-05-01T02:23:14,516 Created build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-y2gd2yu7
2022-05-01T02:23:14,516 Entered build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-y2gd2yu7
2022-05-01T02:23:14,516 Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-wwa3f6hn
2022-05-01T02:23:14,521 Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (62.1.0)
2022-05-01T02:23:14,521 1 location(s) to search for versions of setuptools:
2022-05-01T02:23:14,521 * https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/
2022-05-01T02:23:14,521 Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/
2022-05-01T02:23:14,521 Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/
2022-05-01T02:23:14,522 Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
2022-05-01T02:23:14,523 Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/" in the cache
2022-05-01T02:23:14,523 Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
2022-05-01T02:23:14,524 Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
2022-05-01T02:23:14,595 https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/setuptools/ HTTP/1.1" 304 0
2022-05-01T02:23:14,755   Skipping link: unsupported archive format: .egg: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/38/90cae8fd99c5dc402d25930e1c91f5fcf6de5c8e982fd152a5a061e3df56/setuptools-0.6b1-py2.3.egg#sha256=ae0a6ec6090a92d08fe7f3dbf9f1b2ce889bce2a3d7724b62322a29b92cf93f0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/)
2022-05-01T02:23:14,755   Skipping link: unsupported archive format: .egg: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1f/ab/1ed6131b5112d1d47cb89e1cbea08f783f0ed49d6fc795ed2ff63f84d20c/setuptools-0.6b1-py2.4.egg#sha256=377ff1ce6d8e24842fbc5f7fdf1c64875f7fe9a1c4db9e7b7479cbce1377da86 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/)
2022-05-01T02:23:14,755   Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/cb/906d051fdf1c8b7703d288d3cc44ff32746090378f7f8539c8476a21ce9a/setuptools-0.6b1.zip#sha256=24197f28b1e09f669a5d68eb9ff95f317ec9217f580c34fa73a4d7e6c03f81cc (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/), version: 0.6b1
2022-05-01T02:23:14,756   Skipping link: unsupported archive format: .egg: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/52/c84d22f3669ea8d4e54126f6241d7ed9828e3a382596f170043dfdaddbcc/setuptools-0.6b2-py2.3.egg#sha256=eac0fde9b41f392bcb41ea04975ed41a2e52a067cc14a2737344d3105d26844c (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/)
2022-05-01T02:23:14,756   Skipping link: unsupported archive format: .egg: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/87/48c155a10c4561fe9b8a83dcf9361ddb9cc9ab5c3ed1b504ac12ab11ed6a/setuptools-0.6b2-py2.4.egg#sha256=34a05e133ae5bafc5a0a3b8ca6da29ea3b01a5919a6f0044292220ccf02fc32f (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/)
2022-05-01T02:23:14,756   Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/3b/53daeaf6623a2bab3d3c40b19a35ff5bd7c4e1fbad2f537a61c1fe8c5069/setuptools-0.6b2.zip#sha256=0fdfd2765b4fee3bf7eeb0f9312743c8d81d575b6bd5e7c97c6e2694075a1f05 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/), version: 0.6b2
2022-05-01T02:23:14,756   Skipping link: unsupported archive format: .egg: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/13/a3129905c118a7004e4bbc6db2c24d73de9e15960fd749a61e16fb114f30/setuptools-0.6b3-py2.3.egg#sha256=562410448caaa9295e2dfd07b62fcbc98e281fa0e63207986a0de03668dbb6c5 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/)
2022-05-01T02:23:14,756   Skipping link: unsupported archive format: .egg: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/b3/7166e400d3b953fa4714f97806f077a3f7791cd48ea71df708814234283a/setuptools-0.6b3-py2.4.egg#sha256=2ee23cccdd0ce61c50de9884c707a0c276c9a6fba2a2caa7257d27e2882d9fc4 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/)
2022-05-01T02:23:14,756   Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/33/635de67bf3010651ba8db9d8064721274bfb6fbb778a110089f34beabaf2/setuptools-0.6b3.zip#sha256=0e20067e79c526755e63728b37893a94fc7fc1fd7e3c13d4f20b7ef572104b10 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/), version: 0.6b3
2022-05-01T02:23:14,756   Skipping link: unsupported archive format: .egg: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/d7/6927233caddaa4f466a8b957c94be00810e751edb2655283c04fc3b680f2/setuptools-0.6b4-py2.3.egg#sha256=10b70a682ffacd93f8a56b4cdd1069e4c5027267c717f7764e1a1eaa1d00a265 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/)
2022-05-01T02:23:14,756   Skipping link: unsupported archive format: .egg: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b3/79/8c94b6c99192df5f5d900ce17405cb5cfcdab8643d2e4aaf6ce1ee948576/setuptools-0.6b4-py2.4.egg#sha256=395ea10fe1908fcef2ac021b5c45e86e4a22da95ee6a6101a2cb16a983ddf16d (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/)
2022-05-01T02:23:14,756   Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/be/b2e51157a4debc4ebcab179aeb839948a0f02ce06cbc7749c8ab866c0aa9/setuptools-0.6b4.zip#sha256=2815b909dbe274809c161377cea174cf185019fecded5f01de4d76959a0f06d2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/), version: 0.6b4
...
(eventually finds links)
...
2022-05-01T02:23:14,959   Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/a3/3d3cbbb7150f90c4cf554048e1dceb7c6ab330e4b9138a40e130a4cc79e1/setuptools-62.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=47c7b0c0f8fc10eec4cf1e71c6fdadf8decaa74ffa087e68cd1c20db7ad6a592 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/) (requires-python:>=3.7), version: 62.1.0
2022-05-01T02:23:14,971 Given no hashes to check 1141 links for project 'setuptools': discarding no candidates
2022-05-01T02:23:15,478 Collecting setuptools
2022-05-01T02:23:15,478   Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-unpack-gqvdo0cu
2022-05-01T02:23:15,480   Looking up "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/58/9efbfe68482dab9557c49d433a60fff9efd7ed8835f829eba8297c2c124a/setuptools-62.1.0-py3-none-any.whl" in the cache
2022-05-01T02:23:15,482   Current age based on date: 7886
2022-05-01T02:23:15,482   Ignoring unknown cache-control directive: immutable
2022-05-01T02:23:15,482   Freshness lifetime from max-age: 365000000
2022-05-01T02:23:15,482   The response is "fresh", returning cached response
2022-05-01T02:23:15,482   365000000 > 7886
2022-05-01T02:23:15,482   Using cached setuptools-62.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
2022-05-01T02:23:15,488   Added setuptools from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/58/9efbfe68482dab9557c49d433a60fff9efd7ed8835f829eba8297c2c124a/setuptools-62.1.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=26ead7d1f93efc0f8c804d9fafafbe4a44b179580a7105754b245155f9af05a8 to build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-y2gd2yu7'
2022-05-01T02:23:15,489   Removed setuptools from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/58/9efbfe68482dab9557c49d433a60fff9efd7ed8835f829eba8297c2c124a/setuptools-62.1.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=26ead7d1f93efc0f8c804d9fafafbe4a44b179580a7105754b245155f9af05a8 from build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-y2gd2yu7'
2022-05-01T02:23:15,492 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/58/9efbfe68482dab9557c49d433a60fff9efd7ed8835f829eba8297c2c124a/setuptools-62.1.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=26ead7d1f93efc0f8c804d9fafafbe4a44b179580a7105754b245155f9af05a8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/) (requires-python:>=3.7). Requested setuptools from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/58/9efbfe68482dab9557c49d433a60fff9efd7ed8835f829eba8297c2c124a/setuptools-62.1.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=26ead7d1f93efc0f8c804d9fafafbe4a44b179580a7105754b245155f9af05a8 has inconsistent version: filename has '62.1.0', but metadata has '62.1.0'
(repeat)
```

Can someone shed some light on what the issue might be here? This line here just makes me think pip is broken `filename has '62.1.0', but metadata has '62.1.0'`. I always end up with problems with pip and the documentation doesn't really help. I'm suffering. If anyone can help me with understanding pip or showing me some good documentation because I've seen colorschemes with better wikis/documentations than pip. Thank you

---

Error 2

This issue seems to not be that bad since pip outputs that the package is already up to date.
However, my struggle with pip comes from other places.
Here is another problem I would also appreciate some help

I have `zscroll` installed through pip, apparently, althought I installed it with paru.

Trying to upgrade it to see if the same problem would occur a different error occurs

```
pip install -U zscroll
```

Output

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: zscroll in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2.0.1)
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 189, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 178, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 316, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 121, in resolve
    self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 454, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name, criterion)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 217, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    satisfied = all(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 218, in <genexpr>
    self._p.is_satisfied_by(requirement=r, candidate=candidate)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/provider.py", line 165, in is_satisfied_by
    return requirement.is_satisfied_by(candidate)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/requirements.py", line 112, in is_satisfied_by
    return spec.contains(candidate.version, prereleases=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/specifiers.py", line 790, in contains
    item = parse(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 57, in parse
    return Version(version)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 296, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Logs

```
2022-05-01T03:04:53,090 Using pip 21.0 from /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
2022-05-01T03:04:53,091 Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
2022-05-01T03:04:53,120 Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7211z_oc
2022-05-01T03:04:53,120 Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-0y16dy7o
2022-05-01T03:04:53,120 Initialized build tracking at /tmp/pip-req-tracker-0y16dy7o
2022-05-01T03:04:53,120 Created build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-0y16dy7o
2022-05-01T03:04:53,120 Entered build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-0y16dy7o
2022-05-01T03:04:53,121 Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-xci_zo7l
2022-05-01T03:04:53,125 Requirement already satisfied: zscroll in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2.0.1)
2022-05-01T03:04:53,125 1 location(s) to search for versions of zscroll:
2022-05-01T03:04:53,125 * https://pypi.org/simple/zscroll/
2022-05-01T03:04:53,125 Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/zscroll/
2022-05-01T03:04:53,125 Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/zscroll/
2022-05-01T03:04:53,126 Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
2022-05-01T03:04:53,126 Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/zscroll/" in the cache
2022-05-01T03:04:53,126 Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
2022-05-01T03:04:53,127 Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
2022-05-01T03:04:53,201 https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/zscroll/ HTTP/1.1" 404 13
2022-05-01T03:04:53,202 Status code 404 not in (200, 203, 300, 301)
2022-05-01T03:04:53,202 Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/zscroll/: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/zscroll/ - skipping
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209 Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'zscroll': discarding no candidates
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209 ERROR: Exception:
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209 Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 189, in _main
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209     status = self.run(options, args)
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 178, in wrapper
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209     return func(self, options, args)
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 316, in run
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209     requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 121, in resolve
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209     self._result = resolver.resolve(
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 454, in resolve
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209     state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209     failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name, criterion)
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 217, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209     satisfied = all(
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 218, in <genexpr>
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209     self._p.is_satisfied_by(requirement=r, candidate=candidate)
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/provider.py", line 165, in is_satisfied_by
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209     return requirement.is_satisfied_by(candidate)
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/requirements.py", line 112, in is_satisfied_by
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209     return spec.contains(candidate.version, prereleases=True)
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/specifiers.py", line 790, in contains
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209     item = parse(item)
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 57, in parse
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209     return Version(version)
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 296, in __init__
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209     match = self._regex.search(version)
2022-05-01T03:04:53,209 TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
2022-05-01T03:04:53,245 Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-0y16dy7o'
```

Althought not as bad as an infinite loop, still makes me believe there is something either wrong with pip or with pip in my machine, which is why I have been so desperate with pip, I installed it in a fresh OS just in the morning and it already is being a pain. I just need some help to know if the problem here is me because this has been a very frequent issue I've had with pip for a long time (it breaking after a while and the documentation not helping)

Comment: did you try completely uninstall and delete all cache of python and then reinstall?

Comment: @RajeelRajput yep, just did and the problem still persists, it will continue iterating over all versions of the package.

Comment: You claim it doesn't do anything but it shouldn't do much anyways beyond tell you `Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (62.1.0)`. Your long output looks like it took a second to run. If you could [edit] the post to better clarify what exactly pip isn't doing, that would be helpful.

Comment: The problem is that it will iterate over all versions and not exit if it is already in the latest version. I didn't post the entire log but it will run infinitely over all package versions. My fear is that this is actually not going to upgrade when it really is time for it to upgrade. Also that it should not be infinitely checking every previous version of a package if it is up to date

Comment: I recommend picking a different example then and [edit]ing the post with the new example, because you have the latest version of setuptools as per [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/).

Comment: The only issue I currently have is this since I haven't really had the time for a real update, still it worries me. Checking my packages I noticed zscroll is there which is weird, so I decided to update it and the kind of problem I am getting now is different. I installed zscroll through the AUR with paru so I believe pip is probably assuming it's a pip package wrongfully. Althought, I would be thankful if I could get some insights in the logs to see if there isn't something inherently broken with pip on my machine

Answer (score 1):

### **Update**

I have fixed this issue.

I reinstalled pip with the ensurepip python's module

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

And now I have a working pip!
I am not sure what the previous problem was, I simply installed `python-pip` from the Arch Repository and it was kind of broken (perhaps I installed the wrong package), I also noticed that now pip is in .local/bin which I believe is where it belongs for a user installation.

Hope this can help anyone with the same issue